# Fill in some from HTML form slots using link from another page?

Tags: forms, hyperlink

I have a fairly vanilla HTML page with an (inquiry) form.  That form has  topic field.  I'd like to be able to link to that page from another topic-specific page (using an A tag?) on the website, causing that topic field (and maybe some subset of other fields) to be filled in automatically.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom param (topic name) to the page where the link points and use it as a subject/topic field.

like:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/forms/inquiry.html?topic_title=this%20is%20my%20topic%20title">link</a>
```

Then, on a target page (with inquiry) use this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var params = getUrlVars();
document.getElementById('your_topic_field_id').value = params['topic_title'];
</script>
```

Comment: of course you can fill these fields on server side, but you didn't say which server languages you're using.